# What data structure should I use in objC for key-value pair when the key is numeric?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I have sample data as follows

```
1 -> Apple
2 -> Banana
3 -> Cherries
4 -> Guava
5 -> Apple
..........
..........
```

Now, I need to store this in a data structure in objective C. Like you can see, the keys are numeric and the values are `NSString` type. Typically would've used dictionary but in this case, I can't because the ***key*** is not a string.

I instead started to use `NSMapTable`. Only problem with NSMapTable is, there is no easy way to manipulate things such as, `[NSDictionary allKeys]` etc.

I did see something called as `[Maptable keyEnumerator]` but `keyEnumerator` doesn't look like it can be sorted. So I am running out of ideas on what is the best data structure to use in this situation. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `NSArray` then you need to maintain the order of insertion, to use the index as key.

As `NSMutableDictionary` s are only designed to deal with objects, a simple way to do this is to wrap the integer or float in a `NSNumber` object.

```
NSMutableDictionary *testDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[testDictionary setObject:@"Apple"
                   forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
NSLog(@"Test dictionary: %@", testDictionary);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSNumber` for your `keys`:

```
NSDictionary *myDic = @{
                            @(1): @"Apple",
                            @(2): @"Banana",
                            @(3): @"Cherries",
                            @(4): @"Guava"

                            };
```

Comment: I don't have this values ahead of time. I'd have to initialize them as and when the values become available

Comment: @user1357576 then it's another question. I just showed you how to handle `primitive` (you can say, numeric) type with `NSDictionary`.